# Image preview for two different file input form appear in same div despite having different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have run into a small problem again. I know this is not the most elegant question to ask but I am stuck and need real help.

I am trying to display image preview of the files selected in File input form. I have a small jQuery snippet that reads the files and previews them. The code was working fine with one file input but I decided to add another one just below it and copied pasted the jQuery script changing the file input ID and preview div ID for the second input. But the the preview for the both file Input seems to be appearing in the same div. I am new to this so I am hard time debugging. Help me resolve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    bsCustomFileInput.init();
    function previewImages() {

        var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
        if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);
      
        function readAndPreview(i, file) {
          
          if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
            return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
          } // else...
          
          var reader = new FileReader();
      
          $(reader).on("load", function() {
            $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:100}));
          });
      
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          
        }
      
      }
      
      $('#inputGroupFile').on("change", previewImages);

      function previewImages() {

        var $preview = $('#preview2').empty();
        if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);
      
        function readAndPreview(i, file) {
          
          if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
            return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
          } // else...
          
          var reader = new FileReader();
      
          $(reader).on("load", function() {
            $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:100}));
          });
      
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          
        }
      
      }
      
      $('#inputGroupFile2').on("change", previewImages);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container py-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto">
    
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile" multiple>
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon">Choose image</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon">Upload</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               <div id="preview"></div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto">
    
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile2" multiple>
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile2" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon">Choose image</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon">Upload</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               <div id="preview2"></div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/images.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: function previewImages declared twice so you have to change the name for input file 2

Comment: thanks that worked. I would like to create a function that would apply for all the file inputs instead of copy pasting. For that I will need to pass file Input Id and div ID to the function which will be different for different file inputs. How would I be able to pass that into a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicated IDs: inputGroupFileAddon.

You have duplicated functions.

Your main issue is how you refer to the preview div:

```
 $('#preview')
```

You can change that to:

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('[id^="preview"]')
```

...Go up till the row ancestor and find the element with an id starting with **preview**

In this way you do not need anymore two different functions.

```js
$('#inputGroupFile, #inputGroupFile2').on("change", function(e) {
  var $preview = $(this).closest('.row').find('[id^="preview"]').empty();
  if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);
  function readAndPreview(i, file) {
      if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
          return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
      } // else...
      var reader = new FileReader();
      $(reader).on("load", function() {
          $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:100}));
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto">

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile" multiple>
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon">Choose image</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon1">Upload</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="preview"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto">

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile2" multiple>
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile2" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon">Choose image</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon2">Upload</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="preview2"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

function previewImages declared twice, the second function will override the first, so you have to change function name for input file 2

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the same function to preview both images (`function previewImages()`).

At least, you should rename the second function declaration to `function previewImages2()`

Then update your event handlers to the corresponding functions:

```
$('#inputGroupFile').on("change", previewImages);
```

and

```
$('#inputGroupFile2').on("change", previewImages2);
```